# How to do CSS column layout with a "floating" object spanning multiple columns?

Tags: html, css, css-multicolumn-layout

I'd like to create a layout in CSS that looks something like this:

```
+----------------+ __5_____
|                | __6_____
|                | __7_____
|                | __8_____
+----------------+ __9_____
___1____ __3_____  __10____
___2____ __4_____
```

Basically, the text (in the above diagram, the lines labelled 1 through 10) are arranged in a three-column layout, with a block (image, or whatever) sitting in the top left, occupying two columns, displacing the text.

Importantly, I'd REALLY like to avoid manually specifying where the column breaks are, because the content is user-provided. I have been using the CSS columns family of properties (column-width, column-count, etc.) to get the column layout for the text, but I'm not having much success putting the big floating block where I want. Is there a way to do this that doesn't involve a pile of JS to compute the optimal column break locations, and generating the columns myself?

Edited to add: in case it's not clear, in this example there are 10 rows but in practice I need to be able to deal with an arbitrary number of rows and still get columns of roughly equal height.

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting your image div width to 66% of the container, and add padding in both sides to align it with the white space between the columns:

```
.div-with-image {
    width: 66%; // 2/3 of the container
    padding: 0 20px; // assuming 20px gutters for the columns
}
```

**UPDATE**

As the [current state of the CSS Multi-column Module](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-multicol), the only "natural" alternatives to make an image span through several columns is either through the `column-span` property or overflowing the image inside the column.

However, `column-span` [doesn't support -yet-](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-multicol/#column-span) other values than `none` (default) and `all`, and the overflow won't displace the text in the next columns but [would just cover it](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-multicol/#overflow-inside-multicol-elements) or  [will be clipped](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#overflow-inside-multicol-elements) by the containing column (depending on the browser).

***The cleanest solution that comes to my mind:***

Absolute position your image to the top left corner and define its width to span 2 columns, set the top margin of the first paragraph to the height of your image and insert a break before a dummy element (just a placeholder, could be a `span`) identified with a class. Finally, as that dummy element will be in the first line of the second column, you can assign the same margin top as you did with the first paragraph of the first column.

```
#image-placeholder {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#columnized {
  -moz-column-width: 300px;
  column-width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

#columnized p:nth-child(2) { // the image is the first child
    margin-top: 200px;
}

.break { // your dummy element (I used a span)
    break-before: always;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 214px; // I had to tweak the margin a little
}
```

[image: screenshot]

***Additional notes***

I know that you made your snippet as simple and possible, but, just in case: remember to add `p` tags and make it responsive (best practices). You may want to set the height of the `#columnized` div to use the same break across different screen sizes.

Comment: Thanks. The trouble I'm having is how to "integrate" the image into the column layout so that it displaces the text rather than overlapping it. If you have a full solution I'd like to see it.

Comment: Please share your code, so I can work directly on it :)

Comment: Here's one of my attempts, simplified to remove the surrounding stuff. http://jsbin.com/ticosevufe/1/edit?html,css

Comment: Thanks, this looks quite promising. However, I'm a little confused - the "dummy element" that you refer to, I guess I have to insert it into the text where I want the first column to break? This is overall a pretty clean way to do it, although it seems to still require that I have some JS code to figure out where to put the dummy element. Can you confirm that?

Comment: Yes, but you might be able to avoid using JS if you set the height of the #columnized div and add some media queries changing the width and the count of columns. I think that with a little of trial and error you can accomplish it with 2-3 media queries.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do a simple two column layout and split one in half where needed.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/acspxy2p/)

```css
/* 2 column grid */
.gridWrapper {
    width: 80%;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;

    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.column {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column p {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

.left, .right {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.split {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="gridWrapper">
  <div class="column left">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://c.shld.net/rpx/i/s/i/spin/image/spin_prod_709722401??hei=64&wid=64&qlt=50">
    </div>
    <div class="split">
      <p>1</p>
      <p>2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="split">
      <p>3</p>
      <p>4</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column right">
    <p>5</p>
    <p>6</p>
    <p>7</p>
    <p>8</p>
    <p>9</p>
  </div>
</div><!-- END gridWrapper -->
```

Comment: This solution requires me to manually put "1" and "2" into the first split, "3" and "4" into the second split, and "5" through "9" into the second column. If I don't know ahead of time how many lines of content I have that's hard to do without a pile of custom JS. As mentioned in the question I would like to avoid a solution like this.

Comment: Maybe you can show what you've come up with so far. What content is "user-provided" (image, "1-9", both? and how do they provide that content?)

Comment: Here's one of my attempts, simplified to remove the surrounding stuff. http://jsbin.com/ticosevufe/1/edit?html,css And the "1-9" is user-provided. The image is also technically user provided but I can resize it to fit my needs more easily, so you could say that's under my control.